# How to list all commits in a repository with its parent info along with lines added and deleted using command line or JGit?

Tags: git, repository, commit, git-commit, jgit

How to list all commits in a repository with its parent info along with lines added and deleted using command line or JGit?

Comment: `git log -p`? ..

Comment: Git log -p does not show all commits of repository..

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --all --graph --patch
```

`--all` makes `git` show all branches; `--graph` to show commits by branches; `--patch` to show "lines added and deleted".